# Can not parse the remainder: '==0' from 'data.tab_nid==0'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I my template, I want to give a class `active`:

```
<li>{% if data.tab_nid==0 %} class="active" {% endif %} </li>
```

But when I run the page I get the bellow error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '==0' from 'data.tab_nid==0'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{% if data.tab_nid == 0 %}
```

You should put space before and after ==

Answer (score 1):

You use `==` to check the value if is equal, you should put space around `==`.

And you can also use **ifequal**

Just try this:

```
<li>{% ifequal data.tab_nid 0 %} class="active" {% endifequal %} </li>
```

From the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/), you can find the **ifequal & ifnotequal**'s explain.

Comment: No, django templates support "==".  The problem is that "==" should be padded with space on both sides.  
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#complex-expressions